# How do I fix a "failed to open file at location" error? Specifically a video file

Tags: command-line, video, files, desktop-environments

My command is the following:

```
./build/bin/FaceLandmarkVid -f "./samples/default.wmv"
```

I am trying to run a tool on a video stored in samples folder. It gives me the following error:

```
Failed to open the video file at location: ./samples/default.wmv
```

How can I go about fixing this?

I'd be more than happy to answer further questions if required. Thank you.

Comment: Probably the file doesn't exist or isn't readable. Please post the output of `file ./samples/default.wmv`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment  - it says "no such file or directory". However when I use the command ls in the samples folder I can clearly see the default.wmv file.

Comment: Hmm... try `file ./samples`

Comment: @fresh42juice please [edit] your question to include the output of command `pwd` and the full (absolute) path to your `samples` folder